# not able to return data after doInBackground Method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here is my code. In it onPostExecute() method is getting result as null but I am returning the value from doInBackground() method.
doInBackground() is calling the method getWeatherDataFromJson(). I am getting return arrary resultStrs in LOG(see code) but in onPostExecute() result is null.

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    public ForecastFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
            weatherTask.execute("600001");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
        weatherTask.execute("600001");

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - Sunny - 88/64",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 78/64",
                "Wed - Cloudy - 72/64",
                "Thurs - Asteroids - 75/55",
                "Fri - Heavy Rain - 67/44",
                "Sat - Sunny - 88/76",
                "Today - Light Rain - 81/69",
        };
        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(forecastArray)
        );

        mForecastAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        // the current context
                        getActivity(),
                        //id of list item layout
                        R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                        // id of text view to populate
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                        // array data
                        weekForecast);

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();


        /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
  * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
  */
        private String getReadableDateString(long time){
            // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
            // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
            SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
            return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
        }

        /**
         * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
         */
        private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {
            // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

            String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
            return highLowStr;
        }

        /**
         * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
         * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
         *
         * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
         * into an Object hierarchy for us.
         */
        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
                throws JSONException {

            // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
            // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
            // properly.

            // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
            // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
            // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();

            // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
            int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

            // now we work exclusively in UTC
            dayTime = new Time();

            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];
            for(int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {
                // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                // Get the JSON object representing the day
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
                // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
                // "this saturday".
                long dateTime;
                // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
                dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay+i);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
            }

                for (String s : resultStrs) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry: " + s);
                }
            return resultStrs;


        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

                // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
                // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;

                // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
                String forecastJsonStr = null;

                String format = "json";
                String units = "metric";
                int numDays = 7;

                try {
                    // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                    // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                    // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                    final String BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";

                    final String QUERY_PARAMS = "q";
                    final String FORMAT_PARAMS = "mode";
                    final String UNIT_PARAMS = "units";
                    final String DAYS_PARAMS = "cnt";

                    Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                            .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAMS, params[0])
                            .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAMS, format)
                            .appendQueryParameter(UNIT_PARAMS, units)
                            .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAMS, Integer.toString(numDays))
                            .build();

                    URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built Url:" +builtUri.toString());

                    // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    // Read the input stream into a String
                    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                    if (inputStream == null) {
                        // Nothing to do.
                        //forecastJsonStr = null;
                        return null;
                    }
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                        // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                        // buffer for debugging.
                        buffer.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                    if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                        // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                        //forecastJsonStr = null;
                        return null;
                    }
                    forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                    try {
                        return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG,e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG , "Error", e);
                    // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                    // to parse it.
                    return null;
                    //forecastJsonStr = null;
                    //return forecastJsonStr;
                } finally{
                    if (urlConnection != null) {
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                        return null;
                    }
                    if (reader != null) {
                        try {
                            reader.close();
                        } catch (final IOException e) {
                            Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
            if (result != null) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,"dfgihuffhuffuhgfufdhuidfhudfuhli");
                mForecastAdapter.clear();
                for (String dayForecastStr : result) {
                    mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
                }
            }else {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "errprdvdfdffd");

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are returning null in your `doInBackground`. Check your last line of code in that method.

Comment: @Marcus I am following along Udacity tutorial. It it, try method to call getWeatherFromJson() and return was after finally method, in that case it was not executing it. So, I replaced it inside try(as in code).   If i am removing return then its giving error as return statement required.  In the tutorial video, the code like this.

Comment: @VikashKumar: show full log

Comment: Are you sure that `getWeatherDataFromJson` gets called?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Here is the log. Last line confirms result is null as else is executed. I have omited some forecast entries due to word limit       
02-21 21:23:53.193: V/FetchWeatherTask(4420): Forecast entry: Sat Feb 21 - Clear - 25/23
02-21 21:23:53.197: V/FetchWeatherTask(4420): errprdvdfdffd

Comment: @Marcus yes, forecast entries are logged. In `getWeatherDataFromJson()` i have code to log array of forcast entries.

Comment: @VikashKumar Can you set brackpoint on Log.v(LOG_TAG, "errprdvdfdffd"); line and see the stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that, previous way which you were using to return at last 'return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);' is nice approach. But that was not happening because I think your finally block get executed and your urlconnection object is not null. so it executed 'if' condition and returns null. and last return statement never get called.

As Secondary option, 'numDays' are fixed so if you can send a  'forecastJSONString' as param in the onPost(String resStr). so you can perform next operation inside onPost() method and it will more simpler.